# post Like/Dislike with mongoose/mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Right now my route is doing the following:

1. Searching for the post by id from the request parameters
2. Check if the user already likes the post
3. If the user likes the post, then increase `likeCount` and push `user_id` to the likes array of the current post and vice versa (dec, pull)
4. Adding post id to `myLikes` array of user and vice versa

Any thoughts / suggestions on this code would be appreciated.

```
router.post('/like/:id', (req, res) => {
    User.find({
            'posts._id': req.params.id
        },
        'posts.$',
        (err, doc) => {
            if (err) console.log(err)
            const alreadyLike = doc[0].posts[0].likes.some(like => like._id == req.user.id);

            if (alreadyLike) {
                User.update({
                        'posts._id': req.params.id
                    }, 
                    {
                        $inc: { 'posts.$.likeCount' : -1},
                        $pull: { 'posts.$.likes': { _id: req.user.id }}
                    },
                    err => {
                        if (err) console.log(err)
                        res.send('dislike');
                });

                User.findByIdAndUpdate(
                    req.user._id,
                    {
                        $pull: {
                            myLikes: {
                                _id: req.params.id
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    (err, user) => {
                        if (err) console.log(err);
                });
            } else {
                User.update({
                        'posts._id': req.params.id
                    },
                    {
                        $inc: { 'posts.$.likeCount' : 1 },
                        $push: {'posts.$.likes': { _id: req.user.id }}
                    },
                    err => {
                        if (err) console.log(err)
                        Legend.find({
                                'posts._id': req.params.id
                            },
                            (err, user) => {
                                io.to(connectedUsers[user[0]._id]).emit('likePost', req.user.username);
                                res.send('like');
                            });
                    });

                    User.findByIdAndUpdate(
                        req.user._id,
                        {
                            $push: {
                                myLikes:{
                                    $each: [{
                                        _id: req.params.id
                                    }],
                                    $position: 0
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        (err, user) => {
                            if (err) console.log(err);
                    });
            }
        });
});
```